# nodejs push is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have difficulty making a collection of a class

Match example

and matches

matches is a collection of match

my class match:

```
const uuid = require("uuid");
// Match class is a single game Match structure
class Match {
    constructor(players) {
      this.id = uuid.v4().toString();
      this.players = players;
    }
    // Match rest methods...
    // I.E: isMatchEnded, isMatchStarted ...
  }

  module.exports = Match;
```

my class Matches

```
class Matches {
    constructor() {
      this.matches = {};
    }

    addMatch(match) {
      this.matches.push(match);
    }
    // Matches rest methods...   }

  module.exports = Matches;
```

my main:

```
    const matches = new Matches();
    const queue = new Queue();
    queue.addPlayer(new Player(1,'spt',970));
    queue.addPlayer(new Player(2,'test2',1000));
    queue.addPlayer(new Player(3,'test3',1050));
    queue.addPlayer(new Player(4,'test4',70));
    const playerOne = queue.players.find((playerOne) => playerOne.mmr === 970);
    const players = queue.searching(playerOne);
    if(players){
      const match = new Match(players);
      matches.addMatch(match);
    }
console.log(matches);
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Matches.js:7
      this.matches.push(match);
                   ^

TypeError: this.matches.push is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `matches` property of your `Matches` class is not an array, it's an object. 
You need to change it to initialize an array :

```
class Matches {
    constructor() {
      this.matches = [];
//-------------------^^
    }

    addMatch(match) {
      this.matches.push(match);
    }
    // Matches rest methods...   }

  module.exports = Matches;
```

You could keep it as an object, but you would need to associate a key to every match you add using the `addMatch` function :

```
class Matches {
    constructor() {
      this.matches = {};
    }

    addMatch(match) {
      this.matches[someUniqueKey] = match;
      //ex this.matches[match.id] = match
    }
    // Matches rest methods...   }

  module.exports = Matches;
```

Comment: If I put in a key like I would be able to access my players that are part of the match object?

Comment: If you put a key, you would need this key to access the matches, like so : `this.matches['somekey'];`

Comment: I don't recommend it, it's seams far fetch for what you are trying to do, and an array would work perfectly.

Comment: I understand thanks, do you think me doing this would be the best option / because basically my class match is not good for anything and I could pass the match as an object without having to use a new match

Comment: I think the way you are currently using, with minor fixes, is the best way to do. You just have to pass an object to your matches class and everything else is taken care of.

Comment: Thanks nicolas, you can just ask me one more question I made using the array 
But I can't access my players

Comment: i give on console.log on matches and get this = Matches {
  matches: [
    Match {
      id: '79004a41-3229-42cb-a01e-59dc3ecfd6f0',
      players: [Array]
    }
  ]
}

Comment: But if I give console.log (matches.matches.match);

or
console.log (matches.matches.players)

return undefined

Comment: You should limit your question to one topic. If you have another problem with your code, consider opening another question.

Answer (score 0):

in Node, in order to use push, in your class "matches" you must declare an ARRAY [], not an object {}, then you can use push.

```
class Matches {
    constructor() {
      this.matches = []; //this is an ARRAY [] , not an Object {}
    }

    addMatch(match) {
      this.matches.push(match); //you need first declare the array
    }
```

hope it helps!!

Comment: thanks @jadeblue11.